# How to set scrollLeft in JS while scroll snapping is enabled?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, scroll-snap

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr3soypk/2/) shows the issue.

I am trying to allow horizontal scroll snapping using `scroll-snap-type` so that when the user scrolls, the scroll snaps to the nearest div.

I also want to scroll the div when the user presses a button. However, this doesn't seem to work when `scroll-snap-type` is applied to the container.

As shown in the jsFiddle, removing `scroll-snap-type` makes the button work. Keeping it, makes the button do nothing when clicked.

```
    function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft + 50;
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function(){

    myFunction();

})
```

CSS

```
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
```

HTML

```
  <button id="button"> CLICK</button>
  <div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping" id="myDIV">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not increasing the scroll position enough to snap to the next `<div>`

```js
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft + 400;
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFunction();
})
```

```css
.holster{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
  font-family:monospace
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  overflow:auto;
  outline:lightgray dashed 1px;
  flex:none
}
.container.x{
  width:100%;
  height:128px;
  flex-flow:row nowrap
}
.container.y{
  width:256px;
  height:256px;
  flex-flow:column nowrap
}
.x.mandatory-scroll-snapping{
  scroll-snap-type:x mandatory
}
.container>div{
  text-align:center;
  scroll-snap-align:center;
  flex:none
}
.x.container>div{
  line-height:128px;
  font-size:64px;
  width:100%;
  height:128px
}
.container>div:nth-child(2n){
  background-color:#87ea87
}
.container>div:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:#87ccea
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> CLICK</button>
<div class="container x mandatory-scroll-snapping" id="myDIV">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```